# Ubuntu 12.04 Problem with Internet connection, its very slow on LAN and WIFI

Tags: 12.04, wireless, networking

I have just installed ubuntu 12.04 and i am new to this operating system. i have a dual boot with window 7. My internet connection speed is very good in windows 7, when i test using speedtest.net it reaches a speed of around 10MBPS but where as in ubuntu it shows some were between 1-1.5 MBPS. this is the same either i connect by wifi or lan. 
i have installed all the packages like ubuntu extras.

i request if some one can shower some light on this query, i really want to get this done. 
This is the wifi adapter :  RTL8188CE

Answer (score 2):

Solved, This was due to an application called jupiter which put the system into a power saving mode.

I then changed this option to full performance and it solved the problem.